# Error msg "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Receiving an error msg that reads, "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined". I'm getting the journey passport ID in the view, but the journey passport ID is not getting to the function. Also I'm not getting my console.logs for some strange reason. Any help would be so great!

**Here is my HTML which calls on the 'userLikes' filter:**
(Full code at: https://github.com/cdtdesign/TCP-Express/blob/master/views/blog.html)

```
<a class="like-button" title="Like">
                  <i class="fa fa-heart {{journey.passport_id | userLikes}}"></i>
                </a>
                {% if user.passport_id == journey.passport_id %}
                <a href="#modal-text/{{ String(journey._id) }}#update" title="Edit">
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil journeyEditButton"></i>
                </a>
                <a title="Delete">
                  <i class="fa fa-close journeyDeleteButton" style="font-size:2.875rem;" data-journey-id="{{ String(journey._id) }}"></i>
                </a>
                {% endif %}
```

**Here's the JS causing the issue:**
(Full code at: https://github.com/cdtdesign/TCP-Express/blob/master/routes/blog.js)

```
if (req.user) {
    swig.setFilter('userLikes', function(journeyPassportID) {
      if (req.user.journeys_liked.indexOf(journeyPassportID) != -1) {
        return 'liked';
      }
    });
```

**Also, the code from my Journey model where the passport_id originates:**

```
var journeySchema = new Schema({
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        default: uuid.v4()
    },
  travel_token: {
        type: String,
        default: randomstring.generate()
    },
  passport_id: String,
  traveler_name: String,
  title: String,
  date: Date,
  body: String,
  description_filename: String,
  header_image_filename: String,
  users_who_like: Array,
  tags: String,
    shortlink: String,
  deleted_at: String,
  created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
  updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Comment: Please give us full code.

Comment: `req.user.journeys_liked` is undefined. Hence the error message. You don't have enough context in your question for anybody to be able to guess why that might be.

Comment: @Jits I just added more context and code from the view, where the filter is called on the journey passport ID. Please let me know if this is enough info/code to help troubleshoot my issue. Sorry, I’m a complete noob! In addition to not providing enough info, I'm likely not asking the right questions. My apologies. Thanks for any insight guys!

Comment: How are you calling the `/` endpoint? That bit of code would be useful.

Comment: The error is telling you that there is no `journeys_liked` in the server response. I don't see it in your schema either.

Answer (score 0):

`journeys_liked` isnt being stored in `req.user`. If it's `undefined` that means there's no value for whatever it is you're calling the `.indexOf()` method on. In this case that would be `journeys_liked`. I would say first verify there should be a value for that property in the database. If there is supposed to be one it's a problem with Passport not storing the value in `req.user`.

If there's no value in the database I think you should just make the conditional check for a value, too. That way it'll only run if there's a value like `if (req.user.journeys_liked && req.user.journeys_liked.indexOf()`.

Comment: Thanks @Arcrammer. I see that journeys_liked is in the Travelers model, rather than the Journeys model, but the key nor the value are making it to the database. I thought if the key and type are entered into the model, it should be in the DB. No? How else does it get into the DB?

Comment: You definitely want it in the `Traveler` model since that's the collection `req.user` is being created from. I think you _can_ put it in the database programmatically when the user submits a form or whatever way you choose to approach that (it doesn't have to be through a form). I think if you just populate some dummy records in the `travelers` collection with the data it shouldn't be `undefined` anymore.